# How to validate each character in firstName with yup?

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I have hard times validating every single character in input. I want to return invalid input for firstName if there is something beside simple alphabet characters, ie. if there are numbers or special characters.

This is my code, and i am looking for something which could afford me desired behavior:

```
const FormSchema = yup.object().shape({
    firstName: yup
      .string()
      .max(40).
      .required(),
```

...

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={FormSchema} validateOnMount onSubmit={formSubmit}>
  <Field name="firstName">
    {(props: FieldProps) => (
      <TextField {...props.field} {...textErrors(props.meta)} fullWidth label={t('firstName')} type="text" />
                )}
  </Field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turned out that when i was trying yesterday i was missing dollar sign $, for telling regex to search to the end of the given string input.

```
const FormSchema = yup.object().shape({
    firstName: yup
      .string()
      .matches(/^[A-Za-z ]*$/, 'Please enter valid name')
      .max(40)
      .required(),
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with a found answer!

Answer (score 1):

The answer above did not work for me, but this one worked:

```
const FormSchema = yup.object().shape({
    firstName: yup
      .string()
      .matches(/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖÙ-öù-ÿĀ-žḀ-ỿ0-9\s\-\/.]+$/, 'Please enter valid name')
      .max(40)
      .required(),
```

Comment: You might need a more complex regEx though, for with this one the whole range of name is deemed invalid, e.g.:  Jean-Claud, John Q. Public, François, Noël, Mathéo,  Björk Guðmundsdóttir, etc.


Something like this would do:
`/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖÙ-öù-ÿĀ-žḀ-ỿ0-9\s\-\/.]+$/`